# Can't align print heads enough on Canon Pixma MX722

Tags: printer, maintenance, inkjet-printer

I have a excellent condition, but not brand new, Canon Pixma MX722 printer. I have purchased and installed new, genuine (IE. from Canon) cartridges in it.

Even when I set the print head alignment for black to the highest values (+5) on the printer, I still cannot get crisp black printing. I have run the nozzle cleaning routine.

**Edit to respond to comment of Appleoddity**

Here is a scan of the latest manual print head alignment sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KODLL.jpg

The printer utility asks which value for each column is best. For the columns C, D, E and F even the high end of the scale (+5) is not enough.

Comment: A picture would be worth a thousand words here. I’m assuming by new cartridges you are talking only about ink cartridges? Most likely if you are not getting the print quality you expect it is the printhead that needs to be replaced. However, if the printer has been sitting unused for even a small amount of time, there could be other things clogged like the waste ink pump and lines. It can be fixed but is not typically worth the time, effort and ruined clothes.

Comment: The printhead might need cleaning, which is not a simple operation.

Comment: The problem shown in the image isn't a dirty or bad printhead or even alignment.  Alignment can't correct something that far off.  That looks like mechanical damage, or at least something requiring mechanical adjustment, or a firmware problem.  You might want to contact Canon tech support and see if they can offer any suggestions.  Check the user manual and see if that covers this issue.  Unfortunately, consumer inkjets are now built to be disposable.  There generally isn't even a supply chain for replacement parts because it costs more to repair than to replace.

Comment: BTW, even for printers out of warranty, the manufacturer will often offer you a discount on a replacement printer so they can continue to sell you ink.

Answer (score 0):

I did see someone online say they fixed it by replacing the ink cartridge - and that when they put the old cartridge back in again, the problem returned.  (I don't see how a cartridge could be responsible for this, but if you have a spare cartridge, it's worth trying if you're otherwise going to throw out the printer.)

Comment: This issue came up after installing new cartridges.